# How can I measure the length of stroke used in letters?

Tags: javascript, flash

this question relates to an online design tool into which users can use any font, and enter any word, eg 'Stack'.

The Challenge:
I need to be able to measure the length of the strokes used to write those words (which will vary according to which font they use). The reason for this is because the text that is entered will then be made in to a sign, and the length of material used is a key factor in its price. Using 'Stack' as an example the 'S' will use more material than the subsequent 't', especially in some hand-written fonts.

My questions are whether this is possible 
Whether it is possible using Javascript (the current simple version of the design tool is Javascript)
Or what other types of web-friendly code or software might make it possible.

Comment: Best guess? Calculate the stroke length of each character in a certain font, then use that font, and calculate the cost that way.

Comment: Fonts don't have strokes, they are constructed as outlines (border between character and background). You would have to reduce a rendered image to lines ("thinning" or "skeletonisation", e.g. http://www.inf.u-szeged.hu/~palagyi/skel/skel.html ), or calculate area and divide by average stroke width.